# how does "list.append(val) or list" work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append

While looking for how to allow list append() method to return the new list, I stumbled upon this solution:
`list.append(val) or list`
It's really nice and works for my use case, but I want to know how it does that.

Comment: Believe it or not, `return list.append(val) or list` is more code (and thus slower) than `list.append(val); return list`

Comment: Don't do this, this is rediculous. `list.append`. **always** returns `None`. You are taking advantage of that fact. But just use two separate statements.

Comment: I can see some rare case where you might want to do this, say a deeply nested expression where you need to append the list before one thing happens but after another, but in that case the expression itself should probably be broken up. Python's not a purely functional language, after all. `foo(bar(baz(), list.append(val) or list))`, for example, may not be the same as `list.append(val); foo(bar(baz(), list))`, since it changes the order in which `list.append` and `baz` are called.

Comment: @chepner let me out it this way, I cannot imagine any code that involves this passing any sane code review

Comment: Just saying that rewriting it sanely may not be as simple as just adding a single additional statement.

Comment: Think of maintenance: what if you needed to add a new statement after `list.append()`? You'd need to break it up into two separate statements. So write it that way in the first place.

Comment: @chepner why not just `list + [val]` when needed?

Comment: @Chris_Rands That takes O(n) time and O(n) space to create a new list, compared to O(1) (amortized) that `list.append` provides.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli im using it in a recursive function in one liner if else statement which is why I wanted to include append value into return statement

Comment: @chepner good point

Comment: @chepner im using it in recursive statement and want to send appended list in return statement. ```list + [val]``` doesn't update list and return my final one.

Comment: Without context, it's impossible to say, but you probably shouldn't be using recursion, either.

Answer (score 4):

`list.append(val)` returns `None`, which is Falsy, and so triggers `or` and returns the list. Nonetheless I consider this not pythonic, just make two separate lines without `or`

Comment: I agree that this is not pythonic, even though it is clever.

Comment: @j1-lee I do not even see why this is clever.

Comment: so when it goes into OR statement, the list will already be appended with val and since list is not 'None', it returns list because it's a 'True' statement?

Comment: @VlaryNottellu yes exactly, you got it :)

Comment: @Chris_Rands damn that is clever, im using it in recursive function inside return statement which is why I wanted to use this case.

Answer (score 0):

`list.append(val)` returns `None`, which is a falsey value, so the value of the entire expression is `list`. If `list.append` returned a truthy value, that would be the value of the `or` expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
x=[1]
s=None
print(x or s) #prints: [1]
```

for any future reference, this is how it works.
using  `x.append(2) or x` it will append value, then when compared it will return the True statement between those two which is the list `x=[1,2]`